# $('form').serialize() returning blank locally, works fine on jsFiddle

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, validation, serialization

I'm currently attempting to serialize a form on my page; however, when I run this locally and I use an alert to look at the result of the serialize, it returns blank. When I put this same exact code in to jsFiddle it shows the serialized form (FirstName=somethinghere&LastName=somethinghere... so on and so forth). I can't for the life of me figure out what the issue is.

I'm receiving no errors at all locally, just a blank alert.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k4CTb/)**

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="white-text lobster">get in touch</h1>
    <br />
</div>
<div class="jumbotron no-margin no-padding peter-river inset-top-bottom">
       <div class="container">
        <form id="contact" role="form" style="margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 15px;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                        <input type="text" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="first name" data-invalid-field="This field is required" required /> <!--FIRST NAME -->
                    </div>
               </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                        <input type="text" name="LastName" class="form-control input-lg not-required" placeholder="last name" /> <!-- LAST NAME -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                        <input type="email" name="Email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="email address" data-invalid-field="This field is required" data-invalid-email="Please enter a valid email" required /> <!-- EMAIL -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                        <input type="text" name="Subject" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="subject" data-invalid-field="This field is required" required /> <!-- SUBJECT -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                        <textarea name="Body" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="your message" rows="9" data-invalid-field="This field is required" style="resize: none;" required></textarea> <!-- MESSAGE -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12">
                    <p><button id="contact-submit" type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-lg">send</button></p> <!-- "SUBMIT" BUTTON-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's my jQuery (entire file) with the function I'm having issues with begin contained in the `$('#contact-submit').on('click', function(){});` area:

```
// nav stuff
function goToSection($link) {

    var $elem = $('#' + $link.attr('id'));
    var offset = $elem.offset().top - 50;

    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: offset
    }, 1000);

    $elem.addClass('visible-jumbo');

};
function getCurrentSection() {

    return $(document.getElementsByClassName('visible-jumbo')[0]);

};

$(document).ready(function () {

    // make sure we always start at the top on page reload
    // make sure #home-sect has the visible class
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 1000);
    $('#home-sect').addClass('visible-jumbo')

    $.stellar({ horizontalScrolling: true, verticalOffset: 40 });

    // nav functions
    $('.linker').on('click', function () {
        getCurrentSection().removeClass('visible-jumbo');
        var $elem = $(document.getElementById($(this).attr('id') + '-sect'));
        goToSection($elem);
    });

    // display/hide popover stuff
   $('#contact input[required], #contact textarea[required]').on('focus', function () {
        $(this).popover('destroy');
    });
    $('#contact-submit').on('click', function () {

        $('#contact').validate();

        // can't get the form .validate() to work, this is a work-around for the time being albeit sloppy
        // TODO: cleanup (possible optimization, check timing on this with Firebug)
        // current steps
        //  1. remove any form-control-feedback divs/has-[status] classes from all form-groups
        //  2. validate each field one at a time, if one fails, it exits on that one and doesn't check any of the subsequent fields
        //  3. if there weren't any errors send the email and ajax in the result


        var errors = true;

        // cleanup
        $('#contact .form-group').removeClass('has-error').removeClass('hasSuccess');
        $('#contact .form-group .form-control-feedback').remove();

        // actual work
        $.each($('#contact input[required], #contact textarea[required]'), function (index, val) {
            var $ele = $(val) // get reference to element
            var $parent = $($ele.parent()); // get reference to parent

            if (!($ele.valid())) { // not valid
                $ele.popover({
                    trigger: 'manual',
                    placement: 'bottom',
                    container: 'body',
                    template: '<div class=\"popover\" style=\"width: 200px; border-color: #f1c40f\"><div class=\"arrow\" style=\"border-bottom-color: #f1c40f\"></div><div class=\"popover-inner\"><div class=\"row\"><div class=\"col-md-2 col-sm-2\" style=\"padding: 1px;\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign sunflower-text\" style=\"padding: 11px 28px;\"></span></div><div class=\"col-md-9 col-sm-9\" style=\"padding: 1px;\"><div class=\"popover-content\"><p></p></div></div></div></div></div>'
                }).data('bs.popover').options.content = $ele.data('invalid-field');

                $ele.popover("show").click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });
                $parent.addClass('has-error'); // add error class to parent
                $parent.append('<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback alizarin-text\"></span>'); // add error icon to parent
            } else { // valid
                $parent.addClass('has-success');
                $parent.append('<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback emerald-text\"></span>');
            }

            errors = !($ele.valid()); // if valid, errors will be set to false

            return (!(errors)); // return the opposite of errors, if there were no errors (errors = false), return true
                                // if it returns false, it will stop the .each()
        });

        // send the mail
        if (!(errors)) {            
            var data = $('#FirstName').serialize() + "$" $('#LastName')
            /*$.ajax({
                url: '/Home/_SendMessage',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#contact').serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });*/
        }
    });

});
```

If i serialize each field (with an ID if I add it), like so `$('#FirstName').serialize()`, it does it just fine, but on a form basis it doesn't pick up anything.

Why won't this work locally?!?

Comment: check whether the page contains another element with the id `contact`

Comment: Have you checked whether the browser console shows any errors? This line is an error for example: var data = $('#FirstName').serialize() + "$" $('#LastName'). Did you include jQuery before you used it? Did you include jquery.validate AFTER jquery?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo I made when I was posting it, that line is actually correct in my code. Arun had the solution to my problem, in one of my other HTML partial views that is rendered on the same page there was another element with that same id. Thanks for the input Arun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up being that I had two elements with the same id `contact` as noted by Arun in the comments there. Simply changing one to something else fixed the issue and it is now working flawlessly.